# Autowired injection failed

Tags: spring, junit, mybatis

I wrote a TEST class。

```
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {     "classpath:spring/appContext.xml","classpath:spring/appContext-datasource.xml"})
@Transactional
public class ReadReconciliationFileTest {
@Autowired
private OriginalReconciliationInformationExtMapper originalReconciliationInformationExtMapper;
@Autowired
private ProblematicReconciliationInformationMapper problematicReconciliationInformationMapper;
@Test
public void insertReconciliationInformation(){
    ReadReconciliationFileFactory readFactory=new AllinReadReconciliationFileFactory();
    ReadReconciliationFile read=readFactory.produce();
    List<ReconciliationBean> list=read.readFile("/Users/wuchangming/Documents/work/通联/tlt_javademo/PDS2006040000004450420170216.txt");
    for(int i=0;list!=null&&i<list.size();i++){
        originalReconciliationInformationExtMapper.insertInformation(list.get(i));
    }
    List<ReconciliationBean> list2=originalReconciliationInformationExtMapper.getInformationList(null);
    List<String> list3=problematicReconciliationInformationMapper.getProblematicDataList("9",null);
    Assert.assertEquals(list.size(),list2.size()+list3.size());
}
}
```

In this class, Autowired is valid。
But in the implementation of ReadReconciliationFile class AllinReadReconciliationFileImpl, Autowired injection is null。
[image]

please help me.
thanks!

Comment: Are you showing all your code? Usually this happens when you inadvertently `new` your class under test in your test class.

Comment: Nothing failed to auto wire... You are creating a new instance in the test method yourself... When using auto wiring an `@Autowired` property cannot be `null` (unless you tell it that it can). If auto wiring fails your application simply blows up at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines:

```
ReadReconciliationFileFactory readFactory=new AllinReadReconciliationFileFactory();
ReadReconciliationFile read=readFactory.produce();
```

Will  (probably) create a `AllinReadReconciliationFileImpl` that `Spring` knows nothing about, and thus cannot autowire anything.

You need to `@Inject` the object of this class, and use it.

Comment: thanks！ 
Do i need an object of AllinReadReconciliationFileFactory?

Comment: You need `AllinReadReconciliationFileImpl` that is created by Spring. You usually would either use a factory or Spring, both at the same time make little sense.

Comment: thank you very much。
Your answer is very helpful to me